# Using jQuery variables in a third party javascript library

Tags: jquery, nouislider

I'm making a page that relies on jQuery as well as a library called [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/).

I would like to be able to use variables (for example: `$slider1`) created with jQuery in noUiSlider code but to no avail based on what I've tried so far: [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zsqdthce/1/)

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You did not include the noUISlider library in the fiddle

Comment: NoUiSlider is loaded separately under resources since it’s not available directly in jsfiddle

Comment: I guess you can just initialize with $slider[0]

Comment: @equinoxe5 Please check the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code in jsfiddle.

you just need to change `$slider1` to `$slider1[0]`

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Would you have a quick explanation or URL that explains the reason for this?